# "Error reading from stdin" after reboot

Tags: emacsclient, daemon

I've started using the `emacsclient` more along with the daemon, and I'm a huge fan, but it's started giving me trouble when I reboot my computer. After reboot when I open up a new `emacsclient`, I don't get the usual daemon startup stuff in my terminal. Then once the window opens, I am unable to input anything to the minibuffer. Any time I try typing, for example `M-x` or `C-x C-f`, I get an error message reading `Error reading from stdin`.

Killing emacs with `pkill emacs` and restarting fixes the issue, but I'd rather not have it in the first place. How can I tell the daemon to die, or clean up after itself, when I'm rebooting my computer? If it makes any difference, I'm on OpenSUSE 13.2 with KDE.

Comment: The daemon definitely dies when you reboot your computer, and there should be no need to clean up. How are you starting the daemon?

Comment: I start the daemon with `emacsclient &`. I have `export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""` and `export EDITOR=emacsclient` in my `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that starting the daemon was that simple nowadays... Anyway, your problem looks like you have a script running at system/session start-up and spawning a (non-functional for some reason) daemon.

Comment: I would use "emacs --daemon" to start the daemon, instead.

Comment: I recently got the same error message; my issue was a line in my .emacs that was trying to `(setcdr var 'foo)` where `var` was `nil`, but I didn't see the error message until I tried starting emacs as `emacs --debug-init` instead of using emacsclient – the server/client is a bit finicky like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment of T. Verron, I determined that it was the following lines from my `.emacs` that caused the issue:

```lisp
(require 'server)
(or (server-running-p)
    (server-start))
```

I've used this on Windows to allow me to open a file in an existing frame, but it's only needed there, as far as I can tell, because there is currently no Windows `--daemon`.

Comment: This alone shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but removing it fixed my problem. Maybe it was a combination of this and the way I was starting my daemon.

Comment: Did you remove that lines to solve the issue?